# jssor slider modify $DisplayPieces in relation to device width and orientation

Tags: jquery, jssor

How I can change the jssor slider diplay pieces number in relation to device width and orientation? For now I have only fixed number.

This is my code:

```
   var options1 = {
    $AutoPlay: false, //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlaySteps: 1, //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
    $AutoPlayInterval: 0, //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $PauseOnHover: 4, //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true, //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
    $SlideDuration: 1600, //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 5, //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
    $SlideWidth: 140, //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
    //$SlideHeight: 100,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
    $SlideSpacing: 0, //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
    $DisplayPieces: 5, //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
    $ParkingPosition: 0, //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
    $UISearchMode: 1, //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
    $PlayOrientation: 1, //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
    $DragOrientation: 1
};

var jssor_slider3 = new $JssorSlider$("slider3_container", options1);

function ScaleSlider3() {

    var parentWidth = jssor_slider3.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth) {
        var sliderWidth = parentWidth;

        //keep the slider width no more than 800
        sliderWidth = Math.min(sliderWidth, 800);

        jssor_slider3.$ScaleWidth(sliderWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider3, 30);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Once jssor slider is initialized, there is no chance to adjust $DisplayPieces any more. Please set $DisplayPieces option while initialize jssor slider.

Comment: @jssor is it possible to set the display pieces in the wordpress plugin?I can't seem to find that option